# ubuntu 18.04, shell always crashes(gnome 3.28.2)

Tags: 18.04, crash, gnome-shell

In the last few days, the shell crashes a lot of times in the day.
it happens when sometimes I open programs, switch background, delete extensions and so on...
what can be the reason? when it happens, for ~30 sec the screen is frozen but I can still hear the sound and move the courser.